# Dividing 2 numbers in Hack assembly Language from Nand2Tetris

Tags: assembly

I am supposed to write a program in Assembly that calculate the quotient from a division operation. The values of dividend a and divisor b are stored in RAM[R0] and RAM[R1], respectively. The dividend a is a non-negative integer, and the divisor b is a positive integer. Store the quotient in RAM[R2]. My problem is that it works for all the test cases such as

```
RO R1 R2
2  2  1 
8  4  2 
0  3  0
```

My problem is that even though it works for when R0 = R1 = R2. It doesn't work for when R0 = R1 = 1. R2 still outputs 0 even though it is supposed to be one.  Here is my code

```
// Storing the value in R0 into variable a

@R0 
D = M       // D = R0
@a 
M = D       // a = R0

// Storing the value in R1 into variable b

@R1 
D = M       // D = R1
@b 
M = D       // b = R1

// Initializing R2 to 0
@0 
D = A       // D = 0
@R2
M = D       // R2 = 0


(NOTZERO)
        @a
        D = M       // D = a
        @b
        D = D - M   // D = a - b 

        @END 
        D;JLT       // (a-b) < 0 go to END

        @ZERO
        D;JEQ       // If (a - b == 0)  go to ZERO

        @R2
        M = M + 1   // R2 = R2 + 1

        @b
        D = M        // D = b
        @a
        M = M - D    // a = a - b

        @NOTZERO     // Going back to start of loop
        0;JMP

(ZERO)
        @R2
        M = M + 1   // R2 = R2 + 1
(END)
        @END
        0;JMP
```

Comment: `0/0` is undefined, not `1`.

Comment: My bad I fixed it, the problem is when R0=R1= 1 not 0

Comment: Looks like it should work.

Comment: why is "a -b == 0" handled differently ? this special treatment isn't needed, just let the result be 0, stay in the loop, the next "a-b<0" will finish it